# How to test custom exception with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to learn unit testing with Mockito. This is a method I wrote to authenticate the users that tries to log in:

```
public class AuthenService {
    
    private UserRepo userRepo;  

    public User authenticate(String username, String password) throws UserNotFoundException {
        User user = null;
        if (userRepo.validate(username, password)) {
            user = userRepo.findUsername(username);
            return user;
        } else {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

userRepo is an interface with these two abstract methods:

```
public interface UserRepo{
    
    boolean validate(String username, String password);
    
    User findUsername(String username);
    
}
```

This is my testing code:

```
public class Test {

    AuthenService as;
    UserRepo ur;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        ur = mock(UserRepo.class);
        as = new AuthenService(ur);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void authenticate() throws UserNotFoundException {
        when(as.authenticate("abc", "123")).thenThrow(new UserNotFoundException("User not found!"));
    }
}
```

I suppose as.authenticate("abc", "123") should throw an exception because the DB is empty right now. But I think I am wrong, and I have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone please explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: I see two problems in your code: 1)  you are mocking the UserRepo in your test, but in your code it's that same class that is performing the "authenticate". What is your AuthenService doing then? 2) Your test is not well written, as mentioned by other replies here. If you want to test an exception throwing, you should use a Spy (which uses a real object) instead of a Mock. Otherwise, you are not testing what you want, since you need to stub your method to return (or throw) exactly what you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

You are stubbing instead of asserting in your test, so basically you are not testing anything. A test should include at least one assertion, so it should look something similar to this:

```
assertThrows(UserNotFoundException.class, () -> as.authenticate("abc", "123"));
```

Answer (score 1):

One unit test would be to expect an exception if the validation fails. To that, consider (working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/main/egg_StackOverflow_75025957):

```
   @Test
    public void authenticate() throws UserNotFoundException {
        when(ur.validate("abc", "123")).thenReturn(false);

        // test
        assertThrows(UserNotFoundException.class, () ->as.authenticate("abc", "123"));
    }
```

***Note:*** updated in accordance with comment, re: JUnit 5.

Comment: `@Test(expected = ...)` only works in JUnit 4. You should use `assertThrows`. That has been backported to JUnit 4.13, and allows you to migrate to JUnit 5 more easily.

Comment: Thanks... I have updated the answer and the Github repo to use JUnit 5.